# Make animated background extend to header as background in NextJS

Tags: typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm working on a new project and want to make an animated gradient background extend to the header as a background using NextJS 14 and Tailwind.

In my current set-up, I have the header at the top and the gradient animation below. I tried making the header transparent, adjusting the gradient's top margin, adjusting z-factors and putting a wrapper around the header but to no avail. Goal is a transparent header with the nav bar in white font contrasting the animated gradient.

The animated gradient comprises two JavaScript files. I created the header as a component, which is then fetched by the page.tsx (homepage). The globals.css only includes the Tailwind references. I included the header.tsx and page.tsx for reference. I would be grateful if someone could help out.

**page.tsx (Homepage):**

```
import styles from './gradient.module.css'
import Canvas from '../components/Canvas'
import Header from '../components/header'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <header>
        <Header />
        <div className={'${styles.main} overflow-visible'}>
          <Canvas />
        </div>
      </header>
    </>
  );
}
```

**header.tsx
**

```
'use client'

import { useState } from 'react'
import { Dialog } from '../node_modules/@headlessui/react'
import { Bars3Icon, XMarkIcon } from '../node_modules/@heroicons/react/24/outline'

const navigation = [
  { name: 'Product', href: '#' },
  { name: 'Features', href: '#' },
  { name: 'Marketplace', href: '#' },
  { name: 'Company', href: '#' },
]

export default function Header() {
  const [mobileMenuOpen, setMobileMenuOpen] = useState(false)

  return (
    <main className="bg-transparent relative z-10">
      <nav className="mx-auto flex max-w-6xl items-center justify-between p-6 lg:px-8" aria-label="Global">
        <div className="flex items-center gap-x-12">
          <a href="#" className="-m-1.5 p-1.5">
            <span className="sr-only">Company</span>
            <img className="h-8 w-auto" src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/mark.svg?color=indigo&shade=600" alt="" />
          </a>
          <div className="hidden lg:flex lg:gap-x-12">
            {navigation.map((item) => (
              <a key={item.name} href={item.href} className="text-sm font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-900">
                {item.name}
              </a>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="flex lg:hidden">
          <button
            type="button"
            className="-m-2.5 inline-flex items-center justify-center rounded-md p-2.5 text-gray-700"
            onClick={() => setMobileMenuOpen(true)}
          >
            <span className="sr-only">Open main menu</span>
            <Bars3Icon className="h-6 w-6" aria-hidden="true" />
          </button>
        </div>
        <div className="hidden lg:flex">
          <a href="#" className="text-sm font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-900">
            Log in <span aria-hidden="true">&rarr;</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <Dialog as="div" className="lg:hidden" open={mobileMenuOpen} onClose={setMobileMenuOpen}>
        <div className="fixed inset-0 z-10" />
        <Dialog.Panel className="fixed inset-y-0 right-0 z-10 w-full overflow-y-auto bg-white px-6 py-6 sm:max-w-sm sm:ring-1 sm:ring-gray-900/10">
          <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
            <a href="#" className="-m-1.5 p-1.5">
              <span className="sr-only">Your Company</span>
              <img
                className="h-8 w-auto"
                src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/mark.svg?color=indigo&shade=600"
                alt=""
              />
            </a>
            <button
              type="button"
              className="-m-2.5 rounded-md p-2.5 text-gray-700"
              onClick={() => setMobileMenuOpen(false)}
            >
              <span className="sr-only">Close menu</span>
              <XMarkIcon className="h-6 w-6" aria-hidden="true" />
            </button>
          </div>
          <div className="mt-6 flow-root">
            <div className="-my-6 divide-y divide-gray-500/10">
              <div className="space-y-2 py-6">
                {navigation.map((item) => (
                  <a
                    key={item.name}
                    href={item.href}
                    className="-mx-3 block rounded-lg px-3 py-2 text-base font-semibold leading-7 text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-50"
                  >
                    {item.name}
                  </a>
                ))}
              </div>
              <div className="py-6">
                <a
                  href="#"
                  className="-mx-3 block rounded-lg px-3 py-2.5 text-base font-semibold leading-7 text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-50"
                >
                  Log in
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Dialog.Panel>
      </Dialog>
    </main>
  )
}
```

In my current set-up, I have the header at the top and the gradient animation below. I tried making the header transparent, adjusting the gradient's top margin, adjusting z-factors and putting a wrapper around the header but to no avail. Goal is a transparent header with the nav bar in white font contrasting the animated gradient.

Comment: I figured it out by using Tailwind's '-translate-y-[ ]' function vs. mt-[-[ ]]